# How to create a HTML sitemap for my localhost website?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I have a localhosted website that's not published yet, I need to create a HTML and XML sitemap for it before publishing, is there a way or a tutorial to do so?
Thx

**EDIT**

Well yes it's a self created CMS, something that's created from scratch, yes it's dynamic,
I know that we can use xml-sitemaps.com but I need to publish the website to use it, I need the exact syntax to do so

Comment: Well, we need more information than that. Is this a CMS and if yes which one? Or is it a static website? Is it based on a framework? What have you tried already to create a sitemap?

Comment: Well yes it's a self created CMS, something that's created from scratch, yes it's dynamic,
I know that we can use xml-sitemaps.com but I need to publish the website to use it, I need the exact syntax to do so

Comment: If it's a self created CMS you could go this road: create a controller that handles requests to sitemap.xml which are rewritten to a particular action in this controller. Load the menu structure with all URLs, create the XML-structure using a XML-library in your used language and return a XML-response.

Comment: Just use a tool that can scan localhost / local disk websites (like A1 Sitemap Generator or other deskop sitemap tools)